# Find difference between times in R

Tags: r, time, difference

Help me  to find difference between times.For eg: these are the date and time

```
2015-11-24 16:49:14
2014-12-02 16:52:43
```

Need the result in `HH:MM:SS` format using r.

Comment: Check out `difftime()`, you can select the units you want the information back in. It is base R too.

Comment: Using `lubridate`, try : `as.period(ymd_hms(a)-ymd_hms(b))`, with a and b your two dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code to get the difference

```
library(lubridate)
interval(ymd_hms("2015-11-2416:17:38"),ymd_hms("2015-11-24 14:19:44"))
span<-interval(as.POSIXct("2015-11-24 16:17:38"),
as.POSIXct("2015-11-24 14:19:44")) 
as.period(span)
```

Format of answer

```
> -1H -57M -54S
```

Also display the difference in year, month & date

Answer (score 0):

As you need difference between only the time, ignoring the dates you can first extract the time using `strptime`

```
x <- strptime(substr(a, 12, 19), format="%H:%M:%S")
y <- strptime(substr(b, 12, 19), format="%H:%M:%S")
```

Then using the `seconds_to_period` function of `lubridate` package you can get the time difference and then format the output using `sprintf`

```
library(lubridate)
temp <- seconds_to_period(as.numeric(difftime(y, x, units = "secs")))
sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d', hour(temp), minute(temp), second(temp)) 

# [1] "00:03:29"
```

**data**

```
a <- as.POSIXct("2015-11-24 16:49:14") 
b <- as.POSIXct("2014-12-02 16:52:43")
```